# addGeneratedSourceDirectory fails for generated Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

This works, successfully generating some Java that ends up in my app, as per this [AGP cookbook recipe](https://github.com/android/gradle-recipes/blob/agp-8.0/Kotlin/addJavaSourceFromTask/app/build.gradle.kts#L60-L70):

```kotlin
variant.sources.java?.addGeneratedSourceDirectory(
    project.tasks.register("${variant.name}GenerateBackendsEnum", GenerateBackendsTask::class.java) {
        it.jniDir.set(project.layout.projectDirectory.dir("src/main/jni"))
        it.outputFolder.set(project.layout.buildDirectory.dir("generated/backendsEnum/${variant.name}"))
    },
    GenerateBackendsTask::outputFolder
)
```

So when I change my task to generate Kotlin instead of Java, why doesn't this work?

```kotlin
variant.sources.kotlin!!.addGeneratedSourceDirectory(
    project.tasks.register("${variant.name}GenerateBackendsEnum", GenerateBackendsTask::class.java) {
        it.jniDir.set(project.layout.projectDirectory.dir("src/main/jni"))
        it.outputFolder.set(project.layout.buildDirectory.dir("generated/backendsEnum/${variant.name}"))
    },
    GenerateBackendsTask::outputFolder
)
```

I can see the task has been registered and the new directory is included in `variant.sources.kotlin!!.all`, but:

- my task doesn't get called during app build, whereas it does in the Java example
- if I call my task explicitly, the generated Kotlin file is written to disk but subsequent app builds still don't produce a corresponding `.class` file, and nothing from that file is available at runtime

Most of my app is still in Java but I do have one ordinary hand-written Kotlin source file in `app/src/main/kotlin`, and that also gets built into the app successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with the first example code above but attaching a task that writes Kotlin seems to work just fine. (i.e. writing Kotlin into `variant.sources.java?`).

I'll consider this more of a workaround, until there's any documentation stating that this is supported.